# Verifying if method was invoked with any parameter

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I have a simple update method in my manager class and I need to verify if event was fired.

```
public void editUser(User user) {
       entityManager.merge(user);
       entityManager.flush();
       updateEvent.fire(new UserEvent(user));
}
```

Usually i would do that through the verify method but in this case event.fire() is called with new instance of UserEvent as its parameter.

```
verify(event).fire(new UserEvent(user));
```

This will fail because event was fired with different instance of UserEvent inside the manager. Is there a way to verify this method call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The easiest way is to use `any(Class<T>)`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
verify(event).fire(any(UserEvent.class))
```

Answer (score 0):

If `UserEvent` (and depending on implementation `User`) implement `equals(...)` then it should work.